# Type std_logic is not an array type and cannot be indexed

Tags: vhdl

Checking the syntax of this code: gave me "Type std_logic is not an array type and cannot be indexed." on line 12 and 14.

WHY?!

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Tot_and_module is
Port ( s : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 to 39);
res : out  STD_LOGIC);
end Tot_and_module;

architecture Behavioral of Tot_and_module is
signal temp: std_logic_vector(0 to 39);
begin
temp(0) <= res(0);
gen: for i in 1 to 39 generate
temp(i) <= temp(i-1) and res(i);
end generate; 
res <= temp(39);
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5. Types, 5.1 General, paragraph 4 in part "*Scalar* types are integer types, floating-point types, physical types, and types defined by an enumeration of their values; values of these types have no elements....*Composite* types are array and record types; values of these types consist of element values." (std_logic is a resolved  subtype of an enumeration type (std_ulogic) declared in package std_logic_1164.) 8.4 Indexed names paragraph 3 in part "The prefix of an indexed name shall be appropriate for an array type."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

res is a std_logic - a single bit.
temp and s are std_logic_vectors - arrays of type std_logic

You have:

```
temp(0) <= res(0);
```

This is not possible because res is not an array. Fix it with:

```
temp(0) <= res;
```

Comment: What of line 14?